# Page Not Found Error Multisite Website Posts

Tags: wordpress, multisite

I'm having a strange issue where my Multisite connected sites are receiving a "Page Not Found" error on all Posts and Custom Post Types. The pages/post still exist, as well as the information on them. But when I visit them, I receive the error.

Here's one of the websites in question: [ChromaHue](http://chromahue.com)

I'm not sure what's going on. I have Multisite on, and I have the "WordPress MU Domain Mapping" plugin mapping them to the domains needed. Everything was working fine a couple weeks ago, and now I'm suddenly getting issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switching my permalink structure, and then switching it back seems to have solved my issue.